# Index corrupts memo-field in joined table

Tags: ms-access

to address performance issues I added one index in table A. This table is joined inside a query with table B.
Adding the index corrupts the output of memo fields in table B.
When I remove the index all is fine again.

Hope I made myself clear, if interested I could add some more information about the query itself.

Any ideas on that one?

Cheers,
Ramon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this issues is related to common errors on handling memo fields.
When I change the query function from "group by" to "first", like demonstrated here http://allenbrowne.com/bug-18.html it all works fine.

Strangely enough the error occurred only after I add an index.

Ramon