# ms access query results display problems

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to produce a list of names and addresses of our clients that have paid within a particular timeframe.

Doing a query with just the client table is fine, but when I link in the payment table and access fields from that, the clients address (memo field from the client table) is displayed only as little square symbols. If I leave the payment table joined in on the query but don't print any fields from it, all's well but, as soon as I use data then the address gets fried.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This may be of interest: [Index corrupts memo-field in joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909619/index-corrupts-memo-field-in-joined-table)

It suggests using the solution offered by http://allenbrowne.com/bug-18.html